# Dagger 2 bindings delegation with subcomponents

Tags: android, mvvm, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have a little problem with designing DI architecture of my app. I am using Architecture Components ViewModels and I was inspired how to provide ViewModels via Dagger in their own GitHub [repository](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/388a10dd5a814ba6aaa9bf8dee8e7c1c5840b3a5/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/di/ViewModelModule.java)   .. I want to create scoped component/module for example for product detail that would provide ViewModels/Repositories and other stuff dependent on that single product.. problem is that all ViewModels are provided from the same ViewModelModule as in given example. But ProductViewModel needs ProductRepository that is provided from scoped subcomponent ProductModule. And apparently thats not possible because Dagger throws error at build time that I need to provide ProductRepository with @Provides annotation.

Ok so I thought that I would provide ProductViewModel in my ProductModule but then it crashes at runtime, because provider of my ViewModel can't be found in this [method](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/388a10dd5a814ba6aaa9bf8dee8e7c1c5840b3a5/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/viewmodel/GithubViewModelFactory.java#L33)

Is it possible at all to have this architecture or do I need to redesign it to not use the same method as Google in their sample?

Comment: Yes you will have to study the concepts in Dagger 2 and then rearchitect it to get what you want. This is because in the example the ViewModels are application scoped but you need them to use dependencies from a narrower scope.

Comment: Ok thanks, I get the problem with scopes but I thought that maybe somehow I could combine that. So I just have to provide either new ViewModelFactory or ViewModel itself in my Product scope

Comment: The ViewModels are supposed to have a wider scope than that of the Activity so that might be a problem for you. The dagger-mvp todo-app sample in the Google Architecture Blueprints might be a better fit for your use case

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-dagger

Comment: Yes I know that sample and I am not talking just about activity scope but rather "screen" scope. It will live until user leaves the screen. I really liked in the above example that I did not have to create instances of ViewModels in one method because then the Factory needs to own all dependencies for all ViewModels

Comment: @Billda , have you eventually found a solution to this?

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin yes, the key is to not use ViewModelFactory as singleton and make dagger to inject new instance to every fragment. The same as accepted answer :)

Comment: @Billda, that is quite strange, because I've made my ViewModelFactory `@Reusable`, but it anyway requires all dependencies to be available for all ViewModels from any context...
Maybe your `@IntoMap @ViewModelKey(...)` declarations are decentralized?

Comment: Or you just provide `ViewModel`-s from specific `@Module`-s that are bound to `@Subcomponents`? I mean, centralized `ViewModelModule` is absent in your application?

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin You are right, sorry, that was not the only thing. I also provide scoped ViewModels in  the subcomponent's module. If thats not enough I can provide some sample project if you want or we can chat privately :)

Comment: @Billda , after this update all looks clear: `ViewModelProvider.Factory` will be reused in all subcomponents that provide scoped `ViewModel`'s, and it will work that way. Because if we'll have a single module with `@IntoMap @ViewModelKey(MyViewModel.class)`, than it will try to construct the whole map at this point, and if any dependency for any viewmodel will be scoped, than it is game over. Am I right about that?

Comment: I think so, but as probably most of the people, Dagger is a little bit of magic for me and we are slowly moving towards Koin now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solve a similar problem by removing the `@Singleton` annotation on the `ViewModelProvider.Factory` subclass.

It shouldn't matter whether the factory is a singleton or not; it's only a performance issue, really. I ended up using `@Reusable` instead, which tells Dagger that the factory instance can be safely reused if needed, but without the restrictions of a specific scope.